# Serial reading to UTF-8 decoding

Tags: python, utf-8, arduino, pyserial

I'm trying to create a program in python that reads the serial port, then decode the info received (which in this case is GPS coordinates and an ultrasonic sensor), then I need to create some 'if loops' to save this serial data into variables, but it seems to me that my if statement is not well, below I attach the code:

```
import serial

Ard = serial.Serial(port='COM5', baudrate=9600, 
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, timeout=2)

try:

Ard.isOpen()
print("Conexion con el puerto serial: COM5, establecida satisfactoriamente!\n")

except:

  print("Error")
  exit()

 if (Ard.isOpen()):

  try:
    while (1):

        aux = Ard.readline()
        a = aux.decode('utf-8')
        print(a)


        if a == '1':

         print("It works")
         lat = float(a)

 except Exception:

       print("It doesn't work")
else:

    print("Port is not opening")
```

I tried not using UTF-8, but using  `a = float(Ard.readline())`, it was working (at least printing serial variables as float), but now it doesn't and it never enters the if loop, I tried if `a != 1`, and it works, so the thing is that I don't know the decoding or type of variable `a` is and I need it to be float. I'm reading from an arduino UNO, and I'm using pycharm as python IDE with pyserial, and 3.7 interpreter, please help me.

Comment: You are checking the string `a` to see if it's exactly equal to the string `'1'`. That's unlikely to be the case. It's hard to know exactly what you're testing for.

Comment: I tested a with 1, '1' and b'1' as it seems to apear with no decoding in console

Comment: Also, this is my output:  1

9.9399871

2

-84.0468826

3

44.17
 just floats

Comment: `'1 9.9399871 2 -84.0468826 3 44.17'` != `'1'`. If you only need to know that the *first character* is `'1'`, use `if a[0] == '1'`.

Comment: Thank you Mark, it did not worked, but i simply  encoded (utf-8) 'a' within another variable and then use  if a == b'1\r\n' , and it worked!

Comment: So you really were expecting `1` on a line by itself - that wasn't obvious in the question. Good work figuring out that the `\r\n` sequence is at the end of the string. You can use `a.strip('\r\n')` to get rid of them.